# Search restaurants with filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi i'm trying to write simple search engine. I get url like:

```
.../fragments/get_restaurants?city=London&service=1,2
```

and i would like to search like this:

```
def get_restaurants 
    regions_find = Region.find(:all, :select => "id", :conditions => ["name LIKE ?", "#{params[:city]}"]).restaurants
    cities_find = City.find(:all, :select => "id", :conditions  => ["name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:city]}%"]).restaurants
    regions_and_cities = reg.merge!(cit).uniq
    restaurans_all = regions_and_cities.find(:all, :conditions => ["name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:name]}%" OR TYPE OR KIND])

    filtered = filter(restaurans_all)

    render :partial => "fragments/restaurant", :collection => res
end
```

but i really don't know how make it work.

Here is restaurant, city and region model:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :cities, :dependent => :destroy # dependent only with has_
  has_many :restaurants
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :restaurants_types
  has_many :types, :through => :restaurants_types
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :restaurants
end
```

when i have the result i'd like to filter it by:

```
def filter(table)
    res = table
    res &= table.filter('types', params[:type].split(','))          unless params[:type].nil?
    res &= table.filter('cuisines', params[:cuisine].split(','))    unless params[:cuisine].nil? 
    res &= table.filter('facilities', params[:facility].split(',')) unless params[:facility].nil? 
    res &= table.filter('prices', params[:price].split(','))        unless params[:price].nil?
    return res
  end
```

with this:

```
scope :filter, lambda{|type_name, type_id| includes(type_name.to_sym).where(["#{type_name}.id in (?)", type_id]) }
```

but its not working too. Could you give me some tips how i can do this?

Comment: Let me put on my psychic pants, and then I'll know why it's not working too good.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rolling your own code for this from scratch, I sugget using [Searchlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem with Searchlogic in rails 3.1, but i found Squeel and it's good for me

Comment: Oh no. I love Searchlogic, but haven't used Rails 3.1 yet. Thanks for the tip on Squeel.